# Is there any equivalent to populate in parse-server

Tags: parse-server, populate

I created subject like that

```
  const subject = new Subject({
      subject_name
    });
  subject.save();
```

and then I created Teacher

```
const teacher = new Teacher({
      teacher_name:'teacher neme',
      teacher_age:34,
      subject:'wGvTu03HQd'
    });
teacher.save();
```

when i try to get the teacher object using

```
let query = new Parse.Query(Teacher);
let a = await query.get(objectId);
console.log(a.get('subject'))
```

i get

```
ParseObjectSubclass { className: 'Subject', _objCount: 1, id: '8sB8uibifQ' }
```

is there is a way to get the data from the subject object without using

```
let query = new Parse.Query(Subject);
let a = await query.get(objectId);
```

since it has a relation with the Teacher, something like populate in mongoose?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can use the `include` function:

```js
let query = new Parse.Query(Teacher);
query.include('subject');
let a = await query.get(objectId);
console.log(a.get('subject'))
```

Reference: https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#relational-queries

Comment: David it still give me
```
ParseObjectSubclass { className: 'Teacher', _objCount: 68, id: 'PDbHZARqNC' },
```

Comment: try `console.log(a.get('subject').toJSON())`